# limit mysql query to 1 result?

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have search script running from mysql query. It pulls the matching users from the database if their display_name or location is like the query. When I perform a search for a users display name I get just one result for each user like so:

search 'Tom' = 2 results for tom = 1.tom davies and 2.tom smith.

for whatever reason if I search location i.e. manchester it duplicates the results for each user like:

Tom davies
Tom davies
Tom davies
Tom davies 
Tom smith
Tom smith 
Tom smith
tom smith

Can someone please explain how I can stop it from doing this. I only want it to bring up one result for each of the users that match the search query rather than display the same user several times. I'm sure it's something to do with the select all from ptb_users and ptb_profiles, but I need the 'account type' and 'account_status' to be included which are in ptb_users.

Thanks

```
<?php
//PHP CODE STARTS HERE

if(isset($_GET['submit'])){

// Change the fields below as per the requirements
$db_host="localhost";
$db_username="root";
$db_password="";
$db_name="database";
$db_tb_atr_name="display_name";

//Now we are going to write a script that will do search task
// leave the below fields as it is except while loop, which will display results on screen

mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_password");
mysql_select_db("$db_name");

$query=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['query']);

$query_for_result=mysql_query("SELECT *
                        FROM ptb_users, ptb_profiles
                        WHERE ptb_users.account_type = \"User\" AND ptb_users.account_status = \"Active\" AND ptb_profiles.user_id = ptb_users.id AND display_name like '%".$query."%' 
        OR location LIKE '%".$query."%' OR age LIKE '%".$query."%'");
echo "<div class=\"results\">";
while($data_fetch=mysql_fetch_array($query_for_result))
{
    echo "<div class=\"spacing\"><a href=\"profile.php?id={$data_fetch['user_id']}\">";
    echo substr($data_fetch[$db_tb_atr_name], 0,160);
    echo "</a></div>";

}


mysql_close();
}

?>
```

Comment: You need to provide information about the structure of the database tables...

Comment: Why this: `ptb_users.account_type = \"User\"` ... why oh why? Why not this `ptb_users.account_type = 'User'`? My oh my...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What a query... basically you can either use distinct or group by...

```
"SELECT * FROM ptb_users, ptb_profiles WHERE ptb_users.account_type = \"User\" 
AND ptb_users.account_status = \"Active\" AND ptb_profiles.user_id = ptb_users.id 
AND display_name like '%".$query."%' OR location LIKE '%".$query."%' 
OR age LIKE '%".$query."%' GROUP BY display_name"
```

Group By: http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlgroupby.php

Distinct: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

You can also use LIMIT to limit the amount of rows returned by adding LIMIT 10 for example to end of your query would only allow a maximum of 10 rows to be returned.

Answer (score 3):

Use the LIMIT clause

```
"SELECT * FROM ptb_users, ptb_profiles
WHERE ptb_users.account_type = \"User\" AND ptb_users.account_status = \"Active\" AND 
ptb_profiles.user_id = ptb_users.id AND display_name like '%".$query."%' 
        OR location LIKE '%".$query."%' OR age LIKE '%".$query."%' LIMIT 1"
```

Comment: thanks but i'm not sure i've explained myself properly, say there area bout 12 users in manchester the user will want to search manchester to see who is in their area and want all 12 users to show up but my problem is instead of 12 users coming up these 12 users are showing up several times, so adam is being repeated 5 times and then the next user is being repeated 5 times etc.

Comment: in that case use the GROUP BY ptb_users.id clause

Comment: thanks i did it, i just used the group by clause like u said: GROUP BY ptb_profiles.id

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should be joining ptb_users and ptb_profiles? e.g.

```
SELECT * 
FROM ptb_users AS u
INNER JOIN ptb_profiles AS p ON u.id = p.user_id
WHERE u.account_type = \"User\"
    AND u.account_status = \"Active\"
    AND u.display_name like '%".$query."%' 
    OR p.location LIKE '%".$query."%'
    OR u.age LIKE '%".$query."%'
GROUP BY u.display_name
```

Comment: yea basically i only want to select * from ptb_profiles the only reason i need to include ptb_users is because this tells the search to only display the users who are active 'account_status' = active. and 'account_type'= users apart from that i dont need to include them and its whats causing the results to duplicate